# IK Stretch problem with character's feet: mesh distorts when the bone moves, despite IK Stretch = 0

Tags: mesh, rigging, blend-files, rigify

I was trying to fix this problem by myself 8 hours straight, but haven't succed.
Your help really means a lot to me, if you'd decide to take a look:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LVfNcs-NJGTxYVFaW6c4rezDgfIcV909/view?usp=sharing

My rig has some problems with IK Stretch and I have no living idea how to fix it.
The problem is when you move bones foot_ik.L and foot_ik.R down along the axis Z,
And toe_ik.L and toe_ik.R along any axis, the mesh wierdly distorts.
In the same time, while you move hand_ik.L or hand_ik.R everything works perfect.

I tried:

1. Reparenting all of the feet bones to each other
2. Changing different parameters in the bone properties bar
3. Restructuring the metarig and regenerating it

Thank you for your effort, waiting for your advices or solutions

Notes:

1. mesh destortion by foot_ik https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibpMu.jpg
2. mesh distortion by toe_ik https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGXjm.jpg
3. the bones, which seems to me to be the origin of all the problems https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvOi3.jpg
4. that bone is the only one, which expands, despite of that its IK rig https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiAde.jpg
5. hand_ik works perfectly well https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErL3W.jpg

Comment: It distorts because DEF-foot.L (and .R) stretch to a bone that is copying transforms from toe_IK.L (or .R).  The hand does not stretch at all.  If you want the foot to behave like the hand, then disable the "Stretch To" constraint on DEF-foot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It distorts because DEF-foot.L (and .R) stretch to a bone that is copying transforms from toe_IK.L (or .R). The hand does not stretch at all. If you want the foot to behave like the hand, then disable the "Stretch To" constraint on DEF-foot."
– Nathan
yesterday

Dear Nathan, you don't know how mush I'm thankful to you
For some reason your comment isn't showing in the answers block, so I copied it and pasted it here
For anyone who had the same problem as me - Nathan's solutions works perfect, follow it